# Jquery Slider- Slide right to left and top to bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-slider, jquery-slide-effects

I tried changing the link [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/6sj8x95y/) from fade to slideIn and slideOut but was not able to achieve as i would like to use a slideIn and slideOut style for a project, i am currently working on.

If anyone can help me guide through this, would be a great help.

```
[jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/6sj8x95y/]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47cggt7r/)

```
 /**
 * Fade-cycles elements with class 'banner'
 */
$(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 3000, fade = 1000;
    var banners = $('.banner');
    var len = banners.length;
    var i = 0;

    setTimeout(cycle, delay);

    function cycle() {
        $(banners[i%len]).slideUp(fade, function() {
            $(banners[++i%len]).slideDown(fade, function() {
                setTimeout(cycle, delay);   
            });
        });
    }

});
```

so its using the jquery sildeUp and slideDown

for slide right to left in a cycle here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aps9mozd/):

```
function cycle() {
    $(banners[i % len]).hide("slide", function(){
         $(banners[++i % len]).show("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        });
        setTimeout(cycle, delay);
    });
}
```

Comment: This works for me,just a quick question can it be done side ways

Comment: I tried the following code problem is it only slides left but wont work in a cycle.code is $(document).ready(function() {
    
    var delay = 3000, fade = 1000;
    var banners = $('.banner');
    var len = banners.length;
    var i = 0;
    
    setTimeout(cycle, delay);
    
    function cycle() {
        $(banners[i%len]).hide("slide", { direction: "left" });(fade, function() {
            $(banners[++i%len]).show("slide", { direction: "right" });(fade, function() {
                setTimeout(cycle, delay);   
            });
        });
    }

});

Comment: can you paste a fiddle?

Comment: here is a fiddle with slide left and right in cycle http://jsfiddle.net/aps9mozd/

Comment: is it possible to add a slider bullet to these div it is display: block.